# Angular 4 problema ao setar dados no editor de texto

Tags: div

Eu tenho um editor de texto e tipo word e nisso eu preciso adicionar um texto que vem de um modal para esse editor, com o two way data binding eu consigo setar a variável com os dados que estão vindo do modal e ele insere, porém eu adiciono vários editores de textos, e eles estão vindo com o valor do primeiro editor, eu queria saber como faço pra arrumar esse problema

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <app-tinymce [(ngModel)]="descricao"></app-tinymce>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <app-tinymce [(ngModel)]="descricao"></app-tinymce>
        </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

Cada um vai ter o valor do seu respectivo ngModel se vc quer que cada um tenha um valor diferente vc precisa de uma varaiavel pra por ngmodel pra cada tipo [(ngModel)]="descricao1",  [(ngModel)]="descricao2". vc pode usar o ngfor pra deixar mais fácil veja esse link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314732/angular-2-2-way-binding-with-ngmodel-in-ngfor